# SQL function to round a date to nearest month

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to round a date on SQL to the nearest month using

```
select date_format(date_field, %Y-%m) as date_rounded
```

and getting the error:

> 'Invalid operation: function date_format(date, "unknown") does not
> exist; [SQL State=42883, DB Errorcode=500310]'

Does this function only exist in certain versions of SQL or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: SQL functions depend on the database and version of database, not the "version of SQL". `date_format()` works for MySQL or Oracle, are you using either of those?

Comment: I'm not sure - it's through SQL Workbench

Comment: If it's SQL Workbench and not MySQL Workbench, then you need to verify what actual database you're using to determine which functions you can use.

Comment: what could that be/how can I find out? Could it just be SQL?

Comment: What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: This is a Redshift error.

Comment: yes I think it's redshift SQL

Comment: select version() gives me PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This function will help to round date.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN date_format(date_field, '%d') < '16' THEN
           date_format(date_field, '%Y-%m-01')
         ELSE
           date_format( DATE_ADD(date_field, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) , '%Y-%m-01')
         END as 'date_rounded'
  FROM my_table;
```

It will to the 1st of the current month if the day is less than 16, otherwise, the date will be rounded to the 1st of the next month

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date functions:

```
to_char(
  add_months(
    date_field, 
    case 
      when datediff(day, date_field, last_day(date_field)) < date_part(d, date_field) then 1 
      else 0 
    end
   ), 
  'YYYY-MM'
)
```

Comment: This partly works but I'm looking to round to the nearest 'start' of the month - e.g. 30 June should be July, 2nd June should be June

Comment: that works, thankyou, but is there no simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe there is, but the simplest I can think of is compare the current day, 3 for example with the difference of the last day of the month, say 31, with the current day.